# Why trans-dibromoethane is more favorable than cis-dibromoethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

2 questions:

1. Is trans-dibromoethane more stable than cis-dibromoethane because it's more symmetrical (in terms of molecular weight distribution on either side)?
2. Is it always the case that trans would be more stable than cis?

Comment: It can be generalised that trans is more stable than cis form due to more symmetry

Comment: @Proscionexium I wouldn't say so. Center of symmetry isn't any worse than plane. Big substituents can lead to steric clash in cis, though.

Comment: Is the question about conformational isomers in ethAnes or geometrical isomers in ethEnes? In either case it depends on size, shape, intra [and inter] molecular forces and flexibility. Also Favorable to whom or what?

Comment: Yeah, you can hardly have a cis/trans in ethane derivative - it should be eth**e**ne. Better keep such "details" straight in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean 1,2 dibromo**ethene** (not ethane as that doesn’t have a trans/ cis isomer as no double bond).

The bromine atom is demonstrably large from its position in the periodic table, much larger than carbon or hydrogen. The trans isomer evidently puts the bromine further apart which minimises interactions between them (known as torsional strain). Strain interaction would increase the energy of the molecule and so make a reaction with the cis isomer as its product have a higher (more positive) energy change, which is less favourable.